# different IP ranges for subnets with host systems and router-to-router subnets?

Tags: networking, subnet

Since asking questions with educational purpose in the networking stackexchange isn't allowed I hope I am right here.

I am pretty new to networking and was at first wondering if the direct connection between two routers is a subnet itself and judging from this [picture](http://8185-presscdn-0-22.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/113.png) I'd believe that is the case, but now I am wondering why they used a completely different ip range for the router to router subnets.

Is that a common practice or has it any advantages?

For example if I had the these IP ranges to work with : 192.168.1.0/26 and 10.1.2.192/26, would it be better to split the subnet IP-ranges in a similar fashion to the picture, or does it just not matter and I could as well just use : 192.168.1.0/26 for everything?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.com.  I will try to answer your questions, but it might help to be more specific.

Comment: @ServiceManager Hello and thank you for your time. What I meant is that in the picture we have four subnets. I'd personally just use
192.168.1.0/26 
192.168.1.64/26 
192.168.1.128/26 
192.168.1.192/26 
but I have more then once now seen a setup where the router-to-router subnets, e.g. between router1 and router2 have a completely different IP range, in this case they use 10.1.1.0 instead of continuing with 192.168.2.0 . Does this have any deeper meaning and should I also do this if I am supposed to distribute IP-addresses and am allowed to work with e.g. 192.168.1.0/26 and 10.1.2.192/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection between the routers can be on their own subnet. They can also be on the same subnet extending a subnet, as routers can only handle so many devices, especially for wifi. With personal routers, you have the ranges of 192.168.0.0/16 , 10.0.0.0/8 , 172.16.0.0/12 to choose from for ip assigning. Which IP address assignment you use depends on how many computers you want to be able to handle. Each IP assignment can only hand out so many ip addresses. Now, for the average user, this would never be a problem, as 192.168.0.0 can handle if I recall, can hand out 65k ip addresses or round about. and 10.0.0.0 can hand out way more ip addresses than that lol. Therefore which one you decide to use, is a matter of preference. Unless of course you do intend to connect 65k devices or more lol.

If you kept all the routers on the same subnet, only 1 router should be the DHCP server, otherwise you can run into ip conflicts if all the routers are assigning IP addresses as most consumer routers won't keep track of ip addresses assigned by other routers on the same subnet. Also, the router closest to your Modem would be the gateway for all the other routers and DHCP server, assuming you don't plan on separating your network. But it is usually convenient though to just put the routers all on their own network or subnet and let them assign ip addresses. Now all this really depends on your network needs as the more routers doing routing on your network, the longer it takes for a computer to reach the outside world in otherwords it can add latency to the network. The advantage of extending your subnet from the first router from the modem, is that you would not need to have all the firewalls on every router enabled, you could just use the 1 firewall on the first router, or your modem if your modem allows it.

The only advantage of splitting your network up is if you have a need to keep certain computers/devices separated from the rest of the network but still allowing them to connect via the internet. This useful for things like personal web servers or ftp servers etc. as it makes it easier to not end up with ip conflicts or forwarding ports through NAT and the sorts. This all depends on your needs for the network as well. Disadvantage of keeping separate networks is it becomes more complex with the firewall rules as you will have to maintain the firewall rules on a few different routers if your network is split up.

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty new to networking and was at first wondering if the direct
>   connection between two routers is a subnet itself

Basically, different router interfaces must be on different subnets. This is because, by definition, routers connect two (or more) different subnets. Putting it simple, routers forward packets according to subnets. If two router interfaces would be on the same subnet, how the router could decide which interface to forward packets to?

This is what happens on a Cisco router (Router1 of your example) when configuring both interfaces on the same subnet (192.168.1.0/24):

```
Router1(config)#interface fa0/0
Router1(config-if)#ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
Router1(config-if)#interface fa0/1
Router1(config-if)#ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
% 192.168.1.0 overlaps with FastEthernet0/0
```

So, direct connection between two routers is a subnet itself. Actually, a point-to-point subnet, comprising 2 hosts only, that's why a /30 is often used.

*For the record, a /30 subnet has 4 addresses, therefore using a /30 for only two hosts wastes 50% of IP addresses. That's why a point-to-point link can also use the special-purpose /31 subnet.*

> why they used a completely different ip range for the router to router
>   subnets.
>   Is that a common practice or has it any advantages?

There's no rule for this. I have seen point-to-point links using any subnet within private or public addressing. 
However, when designing a network address plan, for the sake of clarity is good to separate IP ranges for LANs and point-to-point links.
In your example, it is very clear that addresses starting with 10 are point-to-point links and those starting with 192.168. are LAN addresses. The example could have used 192.168.2.0 between router1 and router2 (it works) but that would've been less clear.

However, this is just an educational example. When designing real networks addressing plan, you should take into account many aspects (clarity, scalability, efficient use of addresses/subnets, route summarization, ...)

Comment: thank you for this clear cut, easy to understand answer.